# Social login with JWT on JHipster

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I've added the client id and secret to the yml configuration file, but it's not working. When I try to login with one of the providers, it redirects me to a blank page with the message 'cannot POST /signin/google', if I try to login with Google, for example. I generated a monolith application with JWT authentication and social login feature (I'm using Angular 2+).

Comment: Update: It worked fine when I was not using Webpack to run the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and set properly your `Authorised JavaScript origins` and `Authorised redirect URIs`. First one should be set to just for example `http://localhost` and second one must contain several entries for example 
`http://localhost:8080` 
`http://localhost:8080/signin` 
`http://localhost:8080/signin/google`